# displaying jobs to a user based on the user ID they log in with

Tags: php, mysql

Presently my site is able to display all jobs which have been posted by the admin to any user logged in. however Im trying to edit my code so that it only displays the jobs which are assigned to each user based on their user id. in a previous page, you would create a job for that user and their user ID is automatically assigned to that job.

heres my code for displaying all jobs to the user:

html page:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

        <title>Tyre Hire</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css"/>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <header> 
            <img class="img-responsive" src ="images/Logo.png" alt ="logo"/>
        </header>

    </div>
    </div>

            <?php



            require_once ("config.inc.php");

try
    {
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    }

catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
    echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
    }




            if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    //user tried to access the page without logging in
    header( "Location: add.php" );

}


if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as <b>".$_SESSION['username'] . "</b>,with the status:<b>". $_SESSION['occupation'] ." </b><img class='clientView' src='images/loginIcon.png' alt='client'>"; }
    else { 
    echo "You are currently not logged in";
    };







    $login = $_SESSION['user_ID'];
    print_r($_SESSION);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE user_ID = :user_ID"; 
$term = $conn->prepare($query);
$term->bindValue(':user_ID', $login);
$term->execute();

$login = $term->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    ?>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
    <br>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php">Tyre Hire</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="main.php"> Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="search.php"> Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="all-jobs.php"> Current Jobs <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="interest.php"> Register Interest <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="logout.php"> Logout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="account.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="add.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="right">
            <h2>Current Jobs</h2>
            <p>One of the best sites to find the best qualified and skilled drivers in the UK.</p>







                        <form class="form-horizontal"  action="" method="POST">
        <h3><u>Job Details </u></h3>


    <p>  Select a job below to view its details     </p>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="scroll">
    <?php
foreach($workers as $worker)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    /*echo "<input class = buttonA type=submit name=Apply value=Apply>"; */

    echo "<li class=joblist><a href='job-list.php?job_id=".$worker->job_id."'></a>";
    echo "<a href='job-list.php?job_id=".$worker->job_id."' class=buttonA>View Details</a>";
    echo "<b> Job Role: </b>" .$worker->jobTitle;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<b> Expiry Date: </b>" .$worker->expiry;
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";

}
    echo "<br>";
?>  

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

main php coding

```
function getJobs($conn)
{

    $query = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE user_ID = :user_ID"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    //$stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $login);
    $stmt->execute();

    $workers=array();
    while($worker=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $workers[]=$worker;
    }
    return $workers;
}
```

(the function is called in another file so thats fine)

So at the moment it displays all jobs to the user logged in, but I only want to display jobs which matches the user ID of the user logged in.

Ive attempted it by editing the sql statement as commented out but no luck. I also created a table to handle the foreign keys when I try display the jobs (driver_jobs)
tables:

driver_job table: https://snag.gy/Mm5cU7.jpg

Job table: https://snag.gy/T9yXqL.jpg

any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the schemas of the tables involved.

Comment: ive attached a screenshot of the relevant ones to this task

Comment: do you think I could do an insert query into the driver_jobs table and then retrieve it with an inner join statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the id of the logged in user in the session on successful login.

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id
```

Then you can just fetch all the jobs related to that user by using where clause.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE user_ID = :user_ID"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $_SESSION["user_id"]);
```

Comment: tried that but its saying that the session variable is undefined.: ``$stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $_SESSION["user_id"]);``

Comment: when i log in this is how i grab the user_id: ``$_SESSION['user_ID'] = $row->user_ID;``